# Make content fill the whole viewport

Tags: html, css

https://gyazo.com/1440b13007c6e011ec46218ceecabb6a
As you can see by the screenshot, there is a white border around the main content of the page. Ive tried making everything 100% width etc. but nothing seems to work. The nav bar is just a ul and the bottom part is a container div with other child divs heald inside.

Comment: Check with f12 what is getting loaded and add border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px; to every element

Answer (score 2):

The `<body>` element has a default margin. You need to set it to zero:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding css as below:

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```